# Take every nth row on LazyFrame

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm looking for the rust polars equivalent of the [take_every](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.take_every.html#polars.LazyFrame.take_every) function that is available for `LazyFrames` on python polars.

I want to determine the length of a LazyFrame and decimate it to less than `n` rows by skipping rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Series` has `take_every()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html#method.take_every), you can use it as follows:

```rust
fn take_every(lazy_frame: LazyFrame, n: usize) -> LazyFrame {
    lazy_frame.select(&[col("*").map(move |s| Ok(Some(s.take_every(n))), GetOutput::same_type())])
}
```